# MS Word Macro Insert Delimiter Following Every Chapter in Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have documents that have varying numbers of chapters and varying numbers of sections within each chapter and they are defined as follows, 1:1: 1:2: 1:3:, etc... for a chapter and its sub sections. Then the next chapter, 2:1: 2:2: 2:3:, etc... Each document will have varying numbers of chapters and each chapter will have varying numbers of sections.

I use the following Reg Ex to Find each of these chapter section IDs, (<[0-9]{1,}>:<[0-9]{1,}>:) while turning on the Wildcard option.

What I want to do is at each chapter transition I would like to insert a delimiter, e.g, @. So for example say chapter 1 had 33 sections I would like to insert the @ between the period at the end of the sentence of the last section, 1:33: This is the text of chapter 1 section 33. @ 2:1: This is the text of chapter 2 section 1. So find the first section ID of each chapter starting with chapter 2 and place the delimiter there.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Here's an article that may help: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm